# How to use generated code from Protobuf from a Pip dependency?

Tags: python, pip, protocol-buffers

Let's say I have one Python package where the following is generated from a `foo.proto`:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

package foo;

message Foo {
  string bar = 1;
}
```

Let's say the package is called `foo_lib`.

Now, I want to create another package `bar` that references this. I already pushed the `foo_lib` to my private PyPi repository, and I successfully `pip install foo_lib` in my `bar` project.

Now, I have the following:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

import "foo.proto";

package bar;

message Bar {
  .foo.Foo foo = 1;
}
```

I generate the code like this:

```bash
python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I path/to/directory/where/bar.proto/is -I path/to/directory/where/foo.proto/is --python_out src/bar path/to/directory/where/bar.proto/is/bar.proto
```

This generates the code correctly, but the generated Python code chokes on

```py
import foo_pb2 as foo__pb2
```

because with `foo` referenced as a PyPi dependency, it is located at `foo_lib.foo_pb2`.

Is it possible to somehow tell the Protobuf compiler that it should prefix `foo_lib` or do I really have to generate all dependent Python code again and again?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of deleting my question, in case anyone else has the same problem:

Protobuf is quite a dependency hell.

What I did was: I put `foo.proto` in a sub directory with the same name as the later PyPi package, i.e., `foo_lib`, then rebuilt and redeployed `foo_lib`.

Then, I changed `bar.proto` like this:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

import "foo_lib/foo.proto";

package bar;

message Bar {
  .foo.Foo foo = 1;
}
```

So, when using Protobuf with Python and generating things you later want to reference, **put the proto files in a subdirectory with the same name as the PyPi package you want to create.**

## Followup 1

I also ran into [this issue](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/4176) because the package definition is not consistent with the folder.

To mitigate this, the Python code for all dependent protos must be generated as well in all folders.

This makes using Protobuf in Python pretty much pointless, IMO.

Comment: Had you not deleted the Blazor logout question I'd have added a link to [Blazor Server and the Logout Problem](https://auth0.com/blog/blazor-server-and-the-logout-problem/) that shows how to use `RevalidatingServerAuthenticationStateProvider` to periodically revalidate the authentication state.

Comment: Thanks nevertheless. I found this article for myself in the meantime and am currently reading through it. I deleted the question because it was too general.